# Application SSO between On-premises and Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, active-directory, cloud, single-sign-on

I have a web application (A) which is hosted on on-premises server (Tomcat) and using Active directory for authentication. And also a new web application (B) will be hosted on Azure (AKS) and using AAD for authentication.

My use case is that I would like to implement Single-Sign-On (SSO) after user login application (A), and there is a button/link which can connect to application (B) without sign-in again.

I am thinking whether using SAML or OpenID connect can archive this purpose because both application (A) and (B) are on different platform on-premises and cloud platform. As I found that from Internet, SAML or OpenID connect example only cover same AD or AAD.

Could you please advise is SAML or OpenID or other method can allow user to login on-premises application and then access cloud application via SSO?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such scenario you may need a "Seamless SSO" approach with AAD Connect.
[image]

Refer to these resources for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-how-it-works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start